# 411 - Length Required When Attempting to POST

Tags: c#, .net, http, mobile, xamarin

I am developing a mobile application using Xamarin.  This makes it so I cannot call webRequest.ContentLength = 0.

Here is how I am attempting to post:

Client calls:

```
await new AssetEndpoint().UpdateStatus(Authentication, CurrentAsset, ApprovalStatuses[0]);
```

AssetEndpoint.UpdateStatus:

```
public Task UpdateStatus(Authentication auth, Asset asset, ApprovalStatus newStatus)
{
    return PostResponseAsync(auth, string.Format(
        ApiUpdateStatus, asset.UID, newStatus.Id));
}
```

Endpoint.PostResponseAsync:

```
protected async Task<string> PostResponseAsync(Authentication auth, string apiCall)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(BaseUriPath, apiCall)) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = method;
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Concat("bearer ", auth.Token.Value);
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

So I do go about fixing this error?  I cannot seem to figure out how to set the content length.

Comment: Please show the code for `CreateRequest` method

Comment: @MatiasCicero I have updated the post to include the CreateRequest code.  I broke the code out and put it inside the PostResponseAsync method to make it easier to read.

Comment: @kformeck you don't *post* anything... Where do you write to the *request stream*?   BTW: A strange name *PostResponseAsync*

Comment: Does this work for you? 

`request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content);
request.Content.Headers.ContentLength = content.Length;`

Comment: @LukePothier, no, I cannot set request.Content either.  Xamarin has taken out some of the functionality of .NET in order to keep things small for mobile devices I believe.  So there are some things that cannot be done in Xamarin that can be done in regular old .NET

Comment: @LukePothier which class do you talk about? WebRequest or HttpClient?

Comment: @kformeck can you set `request.Headers["ContentLength"]` ?

Comment: @L.B I was referring to the `HttpWebRequest` that `WebRequest.Create` returns

Comment: @LukePothier *HttpWebRequest* doesn't have a *Content* property.

Comment: @L.B my mistake - I think setting the header's value with `request.Headers["ContentLength"]` instead may be the answer

Comment: To be able to test the solution I would like to know are you using this code in Portable Library or platform specific project (ios/android)?

Comment: @YuriS This code lives in a PCL.  It is code that is common between an Android and an iOS project.

Comment: Is it Forms or Classic?

Comment: What is your Content? Is it string, byte array, etc? I just tested it without any content but with POST and everything works. Now I need to test it with some content. Do you consider to use HttpClient or you have to use WebRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RestClientTest
{
    public static async Task<string> Login()
    {
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(path);
            request.Headers["Username"] = "xxxxxxxxx";
            request.Headers["Password"] = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 };
            using (Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                await dataStream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string resp = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return resp;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you I can provide HttpClient sample if you want to try. Without knowing what you are posting I cannot help more. I also tested this code without sending any data in the body and it works too.

Comment: I don't get it. -2 votes without any comments. I will just stop helping people.

Comment: I haven't looked at this issue since last week so I was not one who downvoted.  I ended up solving the issue a different way; by using HttpClient instead of WebClient.  This was a much easier approach.  However, I will accept the answer you posted because after looking it over, it appears that it should work correctly.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time to test it out.

Comment: @kformeck Thank you. I tested both WebRequest as posted and HttpClient. Both work.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I like your answer.  It should work in most (if not all) scenarios.  Developing in Xamarin is a little different there is only subset of the .NET framework available which can make a .NET developer think outside of the box a little.

Answer (score 1):

It can be the problem in Xamarin version you are using:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/58076#Comment_58076